# Is this row-reduced matrix possible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm reading a Linear Algebra book and this appeared.
If we consider $ad-bc\neq 0$ , the augmented matrix below

[image: Augmented Matrix]

Is row-reduced to this

[image]

However, I've tried to get this row-reduced matrix by elementary row operations in the first matrix but I never get it.

Is there really a sequence of elementary row operations to get that ? Thanks for any help.

Comment: The $4\times 4$ matrix has determinant $-(ad - bc)^2$.   So the row operations to obtain the inverse matrix applied here should also give what you want.

Comment: Yes, the usual Gauss method. You can check it is correct because the values on the right hand side in the 2nd matrix are the solutions to the set of linear equations represented in the first matrix.

Comment: Multiply row 1 by d and row 2 by b. Subtract row 2 from row 1. Divide row 1 by $ad-bc$ and so on.

Comment: @Paul Why not an official answer?

Comment: @Paul I prefer hints and nudges & don't have time to type out longer answers.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is correct. Here are the row operations you can use:

$R1\to R1/a$

$R2\to R2-cR1$

$R2 \leftrightarrow R3$

$R2\to R2/a$

$R4\to R4-cR2$

$R3\to \frac{ad-bc}{a}R3$

$R4 \to \frac{ad-bc}{a}R4$

$R1\to R1-\frac{b}{a}R3$

$R2 \to R2-\frac{b}{a}R4$

You also don't need to reduce it to see it is correct. You can just sub in the answers from the reduced matrix they give you and see that they solve the system of equations.

Comment: What if $a = 0$?

Comment: @PaulFrost if $a=0$ then we know that $c\neq 0$ else $ad-bc=-bc=0$. Therefore, begin with the operation $R1\leftrightarrow R2$ and proceed as normal with $c$ taking the role of $a$ in the reduction

Comment: @A.P. My comment intended to draw your attention to a gap in your arguments. You should edit your answer in the sense that "w.l.o.g. we may assume $a \ne 0$,  the case $a = 0$ requires $c \ne 0$ and can be treated similarly by exchanging the roles of $a$ and $c$."

Comment: @PaulFrost So the inicial assumption $ad-bc\neq 0$ is not enough to get the reduction ? I mean, it's necessary to do as you say ?

Comment: @RuanCarlos It is enough, but it only says that $a \ne 0$ or $c \ne 0$. In the above answer only the first case was considered. You can also do it as Paul suggested in his comment to the question. Unfortunately he did not have the time to elaborate it.

Comment: I've finally understood. Thank you so much.